# Trying to get property of non-object [json] centos

Tags: php, json, centos

I am getting the error: :  Trying to get property of non-object in ...

```
$json_result = json_decode($result);

if ($json_result->status != 'success') { throw new Exception('Failed: ' . $json_result->data->error_message); }
```

But am not sure the issue as It just occurred as I changed operating system of my server.

Comment: Could be PHP version issue, what was previous version and current version s?

Comment: `print_r($json_result)`

Comment: Show me the json

Comment: Are you sure that $result json string has the "status" property? Please can you show the json string?